# Python - Unicode to ASCII conversion

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, ascii

I am unable to convert the following Unicode to ASCII without losing data:

```
u'ABRA\xc3O JOS\xc9'
```

I tried `encode` and `decode` and they won’t do it.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Do you actually need to encode to ASCII, or just to "some 8-bit character set" or "my platform's default 8-bit character set" or something like that?

Comment: It was to ASCII. The database connection was set as ASCII.

Comment: For reference, the string in Unicode looks like _ABRAÃO JOSÉ_

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The Unicode characters `u'\xce0'` and `u'\xc9'` do not have any corresponding ASCII values. So, if you don't want to lose data, you have to encode that data in some way that's valid as ASCII. Options include:

```
>>> print s.encode('ascii', errors='backslashreplace')
ABRA\xc3O JOS\xc9
>>> print s.encode('ascii', errors='xmlcharrefreplace')
ABRA&#195;O JOS&#201;
>>> print s.encode('unicode-escape')
ABRA\xc3O JOS\xc9
>>> print s.encode('punycode')
ABRAO JOS-jta5e
```

All of these are ASCII strings, and contain all of the information from your original Unicode string (so they can all be reversed without loss of data), but none of them are all that pretty for an end-user (and none of them can be reversed just by `decode('ascii')`).

See [`str.encode`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode), [Python Specific Encodings](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings), and [Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) for more info.

---

As a side note, when some people say "ASCII", they really don't mean "ASCII" but rather "any 8-bit character set that's a superset of ASCII" or "some particular 8-bit character set that I have in mind". If that's what you meant, the solution is to encode to the right 8-bit character set:

```
>>> s.encode('utf-8')
'ABRA\xc3\x83O JOS\xc3\x89'
>>> s.encode('cp1252')
'ABRA\xc3O JOS\xc9'
>>> s.encode('iso-8859-15')
'ABRA\xc3O JOS\xc9'
```

The hard part is knowing which character set you meant. If you're writing both the code that produces the 8-bit strings and the code that consumes it, and you don't know any better, you meant UTF-8. If the code that consumes the 8-bit strings is, say, the `open` function or a web browser that you're serving a page to or something else, things are more complicated, and there's no easy answer without a lot more information.

Comment: Thanks. That helped. I had already done the xmlcharrefreplace but as I was writing to a Oracle DB, it put garbage in my string. I solved the issue changing the NLS_LANG param. `os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = "AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1"` and then converting to "latin-1"

Comment: @AdrianoAlmeida: Note that, although Latin-1/ISO-8859-1 does handle both of your existing characters, it doesn't handle most of Unicode. So, as soon as someone tries to give you a Russian or Chinese name, you'll get a `UnicodeError`. If you can set Oracle to use UTF-8 instead, you will avoid any such future problems. If you can't… just keep it in mind, and design your testing accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I found https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/ this library very useful

```
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> unidecode('ko\u017eu\u0161\u010dek')
'kozuscek'
>>> unidecode('30 \U0001d5c4\U0001d5c6/\U0001d5c1')
'30 km/h'
>>> unidecode('\u5317\u4EB0')
'Bei Jing '
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to calculate the `MD5 hash` of a `unicode string` received in `HTTP request`. MD5 was giving `UnicodeEncodeError` and python built-in encoding methods didn't work because it replaces the characters in the string with corresponding `hex values` for the characters thus changing the `MD5 hash`. 
So I came up with the following code, which keeps the string intact while converting from `unicode`.

```
unicode_string = ''.join([chr(ord(x)) for x in unicode_string]).strip()
```

This removes the `unicode` part from the string and keeps all the data intact.