# Splitting record array into sub-arrays, shuffling them, and then recombining them into CSV file

Tags: python, arrays, csv, recarray

Apologies in advance if the question is poorly written. This is my second post ever onto the site and I'm a novice programmer. To start, here's what I'm aiming to do:

> Step 0: Turn CSV File into record array
>
> Step 1: Split record array into two sub-arrays
>
> Step 2: Shuffle sub-arrays
>
> Step 3: Split two sub-arrays into four smaller sub-arrays
>
> Step 4: Shuffle each sub-array
>
> Step 5: Mix and match values between sub-arrays
>
> Step 6: Append sub-arrays to one of two record arrays and then combine record arrays into single CSV file

The first few steps have been fairly simple.

Step 0:

```
import numpy as np
import random
from matplotlib.mlab import csv2rec
from matplotlib.mlab import rec2csv

# Get recarray from CSV file
ev = csv2rec('stimuli_1.csv',delimiter = ';')
ev.resize(60) #for even splits

# Create lists to append data to
audio_files = np.recarray([],dtype = ev.dtype)
audio_files_1 = np.recarray([],dtype = ev.dtype)
audio_files_2 = np.recarray([],dtype = ev.dtype)
```

Step 1:

```
# Split recarray into two sub-arrays
split_1 = np.split(ev,2)
```

Steps 2, 3, 4, & 5:

```
# Shuffle sub-arrays, split again, and then shuffle again
for a in split_1:
    #Set count for mix-and-matching
    count = 0

    #Shuffle
    np.random.shuffle(a)

    #Split
    split_2 = np.split(a,2)

    for b in split_2:
        count = count+1

        #Shuffle
        np.random.shuffle(b)

        if count == 1:
            audio_files_1 = np.append(audio_files_1,b)
        elif count == 2:
            audio_files_2 = np.append(audio_files_2,b)
```

Step 6:

```
audio_files = np.append(audio_files,audio_files_1)
audio_files = np.append(audio_files,audio_files_2)

rec2csv(audio_files,'audio_files.csv')
```

My problem arises here. The CSV files that are produced are fine, except they have a few very weird values. For example, the first value in the 'audio' field looks like this:

> \xb8\xce\xe1H\xeb\x7f\x00\x00\xd0\x12\x81

What causes this? Does it have to do with how I'm appending the arrays to each other?

Answer (score 0):

Does your source file contain Unicode characters? Unfortunately the native CSV module in the standard library will only handle ASCII characters. Those sort of characters are what you will get when something is getting encoded for an extended charset to a lower one. There are a couple of "unicodecsv" packages out there that might help, or adapt their converters to your code (it depends on which Unicode characters you need to deal with).

For reference there is [this classic article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Sposky

Comment: I looked through it and it appears that the original CSV file contains quotation marks, which in "stimuli_1.csv" got converted to Unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

Those are unicode characters. Or at least, they look like [unicode](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).

Some good suggestions for converting them to ASCII at

- [Convert a Unicode string to a string in Python (containing extra symbols)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-unicode-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols)
- [Python: Convert Unicode to ASCII without errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365411/python-convert-unicode-to-ascii-without-errors)
- [Python - Unicode to ASCII conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527279/python-unicode-to-ascii-conversion)

I played around with

```
some_string = "\xb8\xce\xe1H\xeb\x7f\x00\x00\xd0\x12\x81"

for i in some_string:
    try:
        print i.decode("windows-1252")
    except:
        print i
```

And got some recognizable characters.

Comment: Interesting. I could try looping over the Unicode characters and replacing them.