# I want to decode string in python

Tags: python, unicode, decode

Using python, how can I convert a string like

```
'id\u003d215903184\u0026index\u003d0\u0026st\u003d52\u0026sid\u003d95000\u0026ip\u003d14.145.245.85\u0026pw\u003d'
```

to

```
id=215903184&index=0&st=52&sid=95000&ip=14.145.245.85&pw=
```

**update**
the specific problem is when I request  a url, and return:

```
 {"code":0,"urls":["http://vr.tudou.com/v2proxy/v?id\u003d217267950\u0026index\u003d0\u0026st\u003d52\u0026sid\u003d95000\u0026ip\u003d113.68.97.224\u0026pw\u003d"]}
```

so, I want to parse this real urls can access to

Comment: You should at least try something, and ask a specific question when you encounter a specific problem. This isn't a code writing service, although sometimes it seems that way.

Comment: atleast a search in google will fetch u write answer..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527279/python-unicode-to-ascii-conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, the strings are identical. In Python 2, if the string is not hard-coded in your script (in which case you can use a Unicode literal, as Roberto suggests), you can decode it:

```
In [1]: s = 'id\u003d215903184\u0026index\u003d0\u0026st\u003d52\u0026sid\u003d95000\u0026ip\u003d14.145.245.85\u0026pw\u003d'

In [2]: s.decode('unicode-escape')
Out[2]: u'id=215903184&index=0&st=52&sid=95000&ip=14.145.245.85&pw='
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
>>> s = u'id\u003d215903184\u0026index\u003d0\u0026st\u003d52\u0026sid\u003d95000\u0026ip\u003d14.145.245.85\u0026pw\u003d'
>>> s
u'id=215903184&index=0&st=52&sid=95000&ip=14.145.245.85&pw='
```

Comment: I'd avoid the naming a variable like the builtin str-type

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
u'id\u003d215903184\u0026index\u003d0\u0026st\u003d52\u0026sid\u003d95000\u0026ip\u003d14.145.245.85\u0026pw\u003d'
```

Comment: In the context of the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', u'id\u003d215903184\u0026index\u003d0\u0026st\u003d52\u0026sid\u003d95000\u0026ip\u003d14.145.245.85\u0026pw\u003d').encode('ascii','ignore')
'id=215903184&index=0&st=52&sid=95000&ip=14.145.245.85&pw='
>>>
```

### Update

```
>>> unicode_str=u'id\u003d215903184\u0026index\u003d0\u0026st\u003d52\u0026sid\u003d95000\u0026ip\u003d14.145.245.85\u0026pw\u003d'
>>> normal_str = unicode_str.encode('utf-8')
>>> normal_str
'id=215903184&index=0&st=52&sid=95000&ip=14.145.245.85&pw='
>>> unicode_str = normal_str.decode('utf-8')
>>> unicode_str
u'id=215903184&index=0&st=52&sid=95000&ip=14.145.245.85&pw='
>>>
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but why encode it immediately as ASCII? Just leave it as unicode.

Comment: @lvc Thanks Updated answer , please review it.