# Print Dictionary Value From Key Without The Unicode [u'STRING]

Tags: python, dictionary, unicode

I am adding to a dictionary by doing .append within python

```
theDict = defaultdict(list)
theDict[theKey].append(theValue)
```

I'll try to print it out via

```
print theDict[valueKeyToLookUp]
```

But it always ends up looking like this:

```
[u'STRING_I_WANT']
```

I've tried doing print with str() at the front, but it still leaves the u' there.

I tried this: [Python string prints as [u'String']](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599625/python-string-prints-as-ustring) by doing

```
valueKeyToLookUp.encode('ascii')
```

But it still comes out the same. Other solutions look like they are looking up values via the position it is in the list by number, but I need to do it by value.

Any ideas?

Comment: The following question might be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527279/python-unicode-to-ascii-conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dictionary doesn't contain strings, it contains *lists* of strings. When you print a list, that's the way Python formats it.

If you know that the list only contains a single string, just print that:

```
print theDict[valueKeyToLookUp][0]
```

If the dictionary isn't supposed to contain lists, you need to fix that.

Comment: @king it's the index of the first string in the list. Your question doesn't really go into which string you want to print.

Comment: the one that matches the key i put into there

Comment: oh you mean each entry into the dictionary is a list? and you can grab a specific one? each part of the dictionary is actually just one value

Comment: so maybe i dont really need a list to be there

Comment: @king so you have a dictionary whose keys and contents are identical? That doesn't make any sense whatsoever. Maybe you should be using a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)

Comment: no.. i have a key like "theDogName". and a value like, "Buddy". So I want to get Buddy, so I do, print theDict['theDogName']

Comment: @king, build the dict with `theDict['theDogName'] = 'Buddy'` instead of making default values empty lists that you are appending to.

Comment: you mean just start it like that without even declaring it with a list? cool