# Is there something like ord() in python that gives the unicode hex?

Tags: python, unicode

I want to transfer unicode into asci characters, transfer them through a channel that only accepts asci characters and then transform them back into proper unicode.

I'm dealing with the unicode characters like `ɑ` in Python 3.5.

`ord("ɑ")` gives me 63 with is the same as what `ord("?")` also gives me 63. This means simply using `ord()` and `chr()` doesn't work. How do I get the right conversion?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527279/python-unicode-to-ascii-conversion

Comment: `ord("ɑ")` doesn't give me 63.  Can you provide a self-contained example?  `ord` should work fine on unicode strings.

Comment: Try `ord(u"ɑ")`, it should work. Note the `u`.

Comment: Are you sure you're on Python 3? If you are on Python 3, are you sure you have your encodings correct?

Comment: Interestingly, I either get `593` (Python 3) or a `TypeError` (Python 2). That's from copy-pasting `ord("ɑ")` from the question (without `u` prefix). With the `u` prefix, I get `593` for both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: ```ord``` should work.  [```ord(c)
Given a string representing one Unicode character, return an integer representing the Unicode code point of that character. For example, ord('a') returns the integer 97 and ord('€') (Euro sign) returns 8364. This is the inverse of chr().```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord).  Did you try ```ascii(ord(thing)```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error. I used Python via the Windows console and the Windows console mishandeled the unicode.

Comment: you can write arbitrary Unicode characters to Windows console (and even display BMP characters if the font supports them). See [Python, Unicode, and the Windows console](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5419/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian : I solved my issue by switching from the Windows console to the Python IDLE. I think the question you referce doesn't deal with entering text over the console.

Comment: beware: IDLE doesn't support non-BMP characters (e.g., some emoji) otherwise it is a solution if you can't install anything. The solution in my answer there  works for the input too.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a number to a hex string with `"0x%x" %255` where 255 would be the number you want to convert to hex.

To do this with ord, you could do `"0x%x" %ord("a")` or whatever character you want.

You can remove the 0x part of the string if you don't need it. If you want to hex to be capitalized (A-F) use `"0x%X" %ord("a")`

Answer (score 1):

> I want to transfer unicode into ascii characters, transfer them through a channel that only accepts ascii characters and then transform them back into proper unicode.

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps('ɑ')
'"\\u0251"'
>>> json.loads(_)
'ɑ'
```