# Python convert tuple values from unicode to str

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, unicode, tuples

What is the best way to convert the values in tuples from unicode to string, when the tuples are in a list, can it be done without looping?

`unicodedata.normalize('NKFD', x)` can only take unicode, not a tuple. The dataset also includes float values.

#### EXAMPLE

```
unicode_tuple_list = [(u'text in unicode', u'more unicode'), (u'more text in unicode', u'even more unicode')]

print type(unicode_tuple_list)   # list - keep as list

print type(unicode_tuple_list[0])   # tuple - keep as tuple           

print type(unicode_tuple_list[0][0])   # unicode
```

How can all these values be made a `str`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a way to convert this without using a loop/list comprehension.

I would use the `map` function to accomplish this, see:

```
unicode_tuple_list = [(u'text in unicode', u'more unicode'), (u'more text in unicode', u'even more unicode')]
string_tuple_list = [tuple(map(str,eachTuple)) for eachTuple in unicode_tuple_list]
print string_tuple_list
```

Comment: Thank you Michael, this works great except for a part of the dataset with non-ascii characters. 

Is there a way to use map to also force encode the tuple values to ascii?

Comment: If you don't need to preserve the special characters you could look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35536228/7108103 if you do need to keep them you can look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527279/python-unicode-to-ascii-conversion

Answer (score 1):

Unpack the tuples, convert to a string and repack.

Answer (score 1):

```
tuple(map(str, unicode_tuple_list))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.